# Django runserver - page is loading in other PCs

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am running a django runserver from my macbook at home. Able to load the page in my mac. But when i tried copy the link and load the page on other PC the page is not loading. Why? Please help..

Comment: why do you think it should work?

Comment: If you're using the same network, you should execute `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. Then, you need to check your mac's ip then access the ip's port `8000` in your browser.

Comment: Oh thanks bro. It worked

Comment: But what if one of the PC loading the page outside of my wifi connection?

Answer (score 0):

If both computers are in same network, you can use local IP and the port you indicated with runserver command. For instance, if the computer with django app has an IP of `192.168.1.145`, you need to go to `http://192.168.1.145:8000` to access your app in other computers with same network.
If it's about accessing the app from different computers with different networks. We have servers for that. If you have to need the app from your own computer, you need to get a static IP.(It's not recommended though.) Call your ISP for static IP.